# Separation of closely-sized isoforms

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins

I have to separate two proteins of 86kDa and 80kDa respectively, however, I just cannot get a decent separation even in 6% polyacrylamide gel. To make matters worse, these two proteins are isoforms and there is no commercially available antibodies to differentiate either one. I am pretty sure raising an antibody against one of the isoform is not an option for me.

I am tying with the idea of reducing the gel to 4% (I am pretty sure I am pushing it already) or a 2D gel (both isoforms seem to have the same IP though).

Comment: Why are you reducing the gel % ? Increase the % for resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6kDa are usually enough to separate two proteins in my experience. Try the other way, use a 7 or even 8% gel. They run longer but have a higher separation capacity. If you look at this figure from the [LabFaQ](http://lifescience.roche.com/wcsstore/RASCatalogAssetStore/Articles/12115972001_10.11.pdf), you see that you can use a higher-percentage gel:

[image: Separation ranges of proteins in denaturing SDS-PAGE]

The other thing are the antibodies: Where are your isoforms different? 6kDa are 55 to 60 amino acids more for the long form, so there should be enough possibilities to make specific antibodies.